# Subscriber error in ROS

Tags: boost, publish-subscribe, ros

This is my subscriber declaration followed by the callback function

```
 message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point32>
point_sub(*nh, "tracked_point", 1);
    point_sub.registerCallback(&visualservoing3D::pointCallback);
```

The callback declaration is

```
void
visualservoing3D::pointCallback(const geometry_msgs::Point32ConstPtr& msg) 
{
    //Some functions 
}
```

But the following error pops up. I know its something to do with my subscriber.

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225:
error: no match for call to
‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void,
visualservoing3D, const
boost::shared_ptr<const
geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void>
> >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void>
>&)’
```

Thanks,

Nagsaver

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://answers.ros.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
point_sub.registerCallback(&visualservoing3D::pointCallback);
```

You need to bind the non-static member function to an object instance:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

point_sub.registerCallback(boost::bind(&visualservoing3D::pointCallback, p_vs, _1));
```

Where `p_vs` is a (shared) pointer to a `visualservoing3D` object. If you need/wish to bind to a reference, use `boost::ref(vs)`